# Where can I find the transition altitude in different countries/regions?

Tags: airspace, altitude, regulations, flight-level

Where can I find the [transition altitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_level) in different countries or regions?

Hoping to cover as many places as possible. Links to the applicable regulations would be nice.

See also:

[What is the difference between "flight level" and "altitude"?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/13204/1696)

[Where can I find regulations in different countries for flight level rules based on direction of flight?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/37/1696)

EDIT: Instead of request a list, now the question asks for how to find in general. A few examples should still be given though.

Comment: It looks like you're looking for a list, which is a reason to close IIRC.

Comment: @raptortech97 it's also marked as community wiki, I'm not sure how that's handled.

Comment: @raptortech97 I believe lists are generally bad if they are subjective, but there is a finite and defined set of information requested here. I hope it will work but that can be up for discussion.

Comment: @fooot I thought remembered questions that asked for plain lists were not allowed, but I can't find any reference or evidence for that. And if there's no source out there already, the answer's helpful to the internet in general. I suppose the only concern is that there's no clear stopping point, and too many countries to find information for all of them. But I suppose people can just keep adding to a CW answer, so that seems reasonable. Hmm...

Comment: A Google search would be a good place to start with your research.

Comment: @RalphJ There are a lot of instances that mention various places, but usually not authoritative or extensive.

Comment: @RalphJ I could not find good references on this topic searching on Google. This list will probably not cover *all* countries, but can grow to be extensive.

Comment: I don't think it can, or should be not too broad. There appears to be no 'one list' findable on the Interwebz. We can make one. The more countries, the better. At least we're not duplicating wikipedia...

Comment: @CGCampbell I kinda agree, there should be a Community Wiki answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Asia

- Hong Kong: [9,000 feet](http://www.fly-sea.com/charts/VHHH.pdf)

## Africa

- South Africa: fixed and to be at least 1000 ft above the highest ground within 25nm radius of an airfield ([AIC 20.2](http://www.caa.co.za/Aeronautical%20Information%20Circulars/20.2.pdf))

## Europe

- Belgium: 4,500 feet ([AIP Part 2,, ENR 1.7.2](http://www.belgocontrol.be/website/eaip/eAIP_Main/html/index-en-GB.html))
- Netherlands: 3,000 feet (IFR) / 3,500 feet (VFR) ([AIP Part 2, ENR 1.7.1.1](http://www.ais-netherlands.nl/aim/index.html))

## Oceania

- Australia: 10,000 feet MSL ([AIP ENR 1.7 (2.1.1))](https://www.airservicesaustralia.com/aip/current/aip/enroute.pdf)
- New Zealand: 13,000 feet AMSL ([CAA CAR 91.425](https://www.caa.govt.nz/rules/Rule_Consolidations/Part_091_Consolidation.pdf))

## North America

- Canada: 18,000 feet ([SOR/96-433 602.34](http://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/regulations/SOR-96-433/FullText.html#s-602.34))
- United States: 18,000 feet MSL ([14 CFR §91.121](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?node=se14.2.91_1121))

## South America

- Argentina: Depends on terminal airspace
- Brasil: Depends on terminal airspace
- Chile: Depends on terminal airspace
- Colombia: 18,000 ft ([SAM/IG/12-NE/23](http://www.icao.int/SAM/Documents/2013-SAMIG12/SAMIG12_NE23.pdf))
- Ecuador: Depends on terminal airspace
- Paraguay: 3000 ft ([SAM/IG/12-NE/23](http://www.icao.int/SAM/Documents/2013-SAMIG12/SAMIG12_NE23.pdf))
- Perú: Depends on terminal airspace
- Uruguay: 3000 ft ([SAM/IG/12-NE/23](http://www.icao.int/SAM/Documents/2013-SAMIG12/SAMIG12_NE23.pdf))
- Venezuela: Depends on terminal airspace